# Selenium webdriver refresh page

Tags: python, selenium

I'm attempting to load the tree structure using selenium

```
    driver.get('http://someurl.com/signup')
    email_field = driver.find_element_by_id('email')
    pass_field = driver.find_element_by_id('newPassword')
    confirm_pass_field = driver.find_element_by_id('confirmPassword')
    for i in range (ord('2'),ord(end)+1):
        j = chr(i)
        sendValue(email_field,'randomemail+abc%s@gmail.com'%j)
        sendValue(pass_field,'bobsayshi')
        sendValue(confirm_pass_field,'bobsayshi')
        #click submit button
        driver.get('http://someurl.com/signup')
```

Here i'm trying to retain the structure of the tree for easier access every successive time. It takes almost 15 odd seconds for the compiler to locate the objects from the webpage and so, I've decided to load the tree structure and make the variables point to the specific form fields and then use the same thereafter.

This is not the case as every time I refresh the page, the variables pointing to the form fields are reset.
Is there any way to circumvent this and use the same structure?

Structure of sendValue :

```
def sendValue(obj,val):
    obj.send_keys(val)
```

Comment: this may not be relevant but you have two driver.get's in your for loop - this is unnecessary, and will definitely add to your run time.

Comment: yeah I noticed that when compiling my code and I've edited it out. Thanks for pointing that out, but it really doesn't affect runtime as much as compared to finding the hierarchy of the html objects.